# I can send the images and rar files but that files was corrupted using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, email-attachments

i am using asp.net and c#.net to send the mail with large attachments(max 10mb), that the reason i can convert the files, .txt,.doc,.xls file are perfectly sending but images and rar file corrupted what is the problem please give me any suggestion ,
**My code is**

```
 DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(con, "usp_GetEmailSettings", Session["UserID"].ToString());
                message.To.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Email"].ToString());
                message.CC.Add(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["EmailID"].ToString());
                message.Subject = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Email_Subject"].ToString();
                message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["EmailID"].ToString());
                message.Body = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Email_Body"].ToString() +
                                       "<br/><br/> <font size='2.0em'>Submission Number : " +filename+"<br/> DBA Name : " +txtDBAName.Text + "<br/> Insured Name : " +TxtInsured.Text + "<br/> Additional Comments : " + txtcomment.Value ;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                string attachId;
                System.Net.Mail.Attachment at;
 // Get the HttpFileCollection and Attach the Multiple files
                HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
                if (hfc.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                        if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            if (i == 0)
                            {
                                string[] ext = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName).Split('.');
                                attachId = filename + "." + ext[1];
                                at = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(fluuploader.FileContent, attachId);
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                string[] ext = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName).Split('.');
                                attachId = filename + "(" + i + ")" + "." + ext[1];
                                at = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(fluuploader.FileContent, attachId);
                            }
                            at.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.SevenBit;
                           // at.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.QuotedPrintable;                       
                            message.Attachments.Add(at);
                        }

                    }
                }
 smtp.Timeout = 9999999;
                smtp.Send(message);
```

web.config my code is

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480"/>
```

**at.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.SevenBit;** i can give the comment in that line doesnot send the large files but all are perfectly working  but i have send the large files maximum 10mb , pls give me suggestion

Comment: Seems to me that Base64 encoding would be safer for binary files.   SevenBit pretty much means "no encoding", and you're basically relying on all the mail servers along the way to be 8-bit clean...and many aren't.

Comment: Base64 also checking there is no use same problem

Comment: How do u know it's corrupted.r u getting corrupted files when u are downloading files? if yes possibly a issue with that code.

Comment: i opend that image error is "Windows Photo Viewer cannot display the picture because the file is Empty" and rar file also same error

Comment: You may want to mention what this `fluuploader` is...cause it seems to have a rather important role in this whole mess.

Comment: i Attached multiple files using jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless there is some black magic taking place behind the scenes, I think you need to swap out `fluuploader.FileContent` with `hpf.InputStream`. Also, I find it helps to set the Position of the InputStream to 0. Your final code inside the for loop should look something like this:

```
    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];

    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        hpf.InputStream.Position = 0;

        if (i == 0)
        {
            string[] ext = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName).Split('.');
            attachId = filename + "." + ext[1];
            at = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(hpf.InputStream, attachId);
        }

        else
        {
            string[] ext = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName).Split('.');
            attachId = filename + "(" + i + ")" + "." + ext[1];
            at = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(hpf.InputStream, attachId);
        }

        message.Attachments.Add(at);
    }
```

Comment: not working Error Message is "Failure Sending Mail" , I attached 4mb file please give suggestion

Comment: You can try setting the TransferEncoding or installing this hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2183292

Comment: `hpf.InputStream.Position = 0;` was key for us. We both save the files to our DB using `var buffer = new byte[hpf.ContentLength]; hpf.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` and then email them. For some reason we were getting empty files on the emails. Not too knowledgeable on the subject but I assume the `Position` had changed after saving to the db.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code . This should work I am attaching nearly 25MB zip file

```
public static void CreateMessageWithAttachment(string server)
    {
        // Specify the file to be attached and sent.
        // This example assumes that a file named Data.xls exists in the
        // current working directory.
        string file = "data.xls";
        // Create a message and set up the recipients.
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
           "jane@contoso.com",
           "ben@contoso.com",
           "Quarterly data report.",
           "See the attached spreadsheet.");

        // Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
        Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        // Add time stamp information for the file.
        ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
        disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
        disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
        disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
        // Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
        message.Attachments.Add(data);

        //Send the message.
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
        // Add credentials if the SMTP server requires them.
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

  try {
          client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
          Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateMessageWithAttachment(): {0}", 
                ex.ToString() );              
        }
        // Display the values in the ContentDisposition for the attachment.
        ContentDisposition cd = data.ContentDisposition;
        Console.WriteLine("Content disposition");
        Console.WriteLine(cd.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("File {0}", cd.FileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Size {0}", cd.Size);
        Console.WriteLine("Creation {0}", cd.CreationDate);
        Console.WriteLine("Modification {0}", cd.ModificationDate);
        Console.WriteLine("Read {0}", cd.ReadDate);
        Console.WriteLine("Inline {0}", cd.Inline);
        Console.WriteLine("Parameters: {0}", cd.Parameters.Count);
        foreach (DictionaryEntry d in cd.Parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", d.Key, d.Value);
        }
        data.Dispose();
    }
```

if you get error please post back